# Bluetooth requestDevice() is undefined on Amazon Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

The following example (1) lists available Bluetooth devices when opened as a file in Chrome version 70.

When uploading the same exact example to an Amazon Ligtsail instance I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestDevice' of undefined
at connect ((index):9)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):4)
```

Can anyone explain to me what the issue might be? Since this is JavaScript, it should be executed in the browser and be unrelated to any server setup?

.

**(1) Example code that generates the error on Amazon Lightsail**

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="connect();">Click here</button>
<script>
function connect() {
    console.log('Getting Bluetooth Device...');
    navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(
    {
        acceptAllDevices : true
    })
    .then(device => {
        console.log('Got device');
    })
     .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you access via an HTTPS endpoint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @kdgregory suggested, the `navigator.bluetooth` is [HTTPS only](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web#https_only):

> Because this experimental API is a powerful new feature added to the Web, Google Chrome aims to make it available only to secure contexts. This means you'll need to build with TLS in mind.

I added a [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/) and it works.

[image]

Comment: I thought that might be the problem but didn't have the time to look. Glad to see that you were able to solve it, and write a good answer explaining it.